# "job postings" and "job posts", what is the difference

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I was thinking about this problem. Why don't we say "job posts" like "blog posts", as opposed to say "job postings".

Comment: We do say "job posts" as well as "posted jobs".   Try a Google search and you'll see all the results.

Comment: @Andrew but I think `job postings` are the most pervasive

Comment: This is true, and you can confirm it with [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=job+posting%2C+job+post&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).  But as for "why", you might as well ask why we call it "texting" instead of "noting".  In any language, sometimes words are popular just because.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "Job postings" and "job posts" are used, and both are perfectly correct and natural. Either would be understood, and there is no significant difference in meaning. As to why one is more popular than the other, that is just a matter of fashion or style.